# Objective C String Separation

Tags: objective-c

I currently have several arrays of strings which join together into one array of strings for a search. @"%@ | %@ | %@ | %@ | %@ | %@". Now I am trying to separate the contents of the large array of strings,  @"%@", back into the original six strings. Is there any way I can do this. Yes it sounds redundant but it is necessary at this point of development.

Edit: For clarification, I am using six parallel arrays and inserting each corresponding value between the pipes and converting it into a combined array of strings. I want to separate 
"Word A | Word B | Word C | Word D | Word E | Word F", into
NSString A = "Word A";
NSString B = "Word B";
etc.

Comment: I think you might need to explain a litter further and  post some code for this one.

Comment: You might try reviewing the spec for NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate this string you can use:

```
NSArray *array = [yourStrngToSeparate componentsSeparatedByString:@" | "];
```

If you want to put it back to string you don't have to use stringWithFormat, you can do:

```
NSString *string = [array componentsJoinedByString:@" | "];
```